# Insert radio button value to mysql with click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a survey which displays a happy and sad face

When the user clicks on the radio button it should preform the onclick event

The PHP should then submit it to the database but when clicking the radio button its not running the php, i'm trying to think about how i can submit it do i need to run the php from within that page and not having it as a form action.

```
 <html>
<head>
  <title>survey</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <img src="Wincanton.png" alt="wincantonLogo" class="wincantonLogo" />
    <img src="Screwfix.jpg" alt="screwfixLogo" class="screwfixLogo" />

    <h1 class="Survey_Title">Heath and Wellbeing</h1><br />

    <h2 class="Survey_Question">Did you find the most recent Wellbeing campaign useful?</h2><br/>



      <div class="cc-selector">
      <form class="cc-selector" id="form-id" action="tester.php" method="POST">
    <label><input id="happy" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" onclick="document.getElementById('cc-selector').click();" /></label>
    <label class="drinkcard-cc happy" for="happy"></label>
    <label><input id="sad" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" onclick="document.getElementById('cc-selector').click();" /></label>
    <label class="drinkcard-cc sad"for="sad"></label>
  </form>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".cc-selector").html(
    $(".cc-selector").children().sort(function(a, b) {
    return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.8;
    })
    );
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



 <?php if(array_key_exists('radioAnswer', $_POST)) {


  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = 'rootpassword';
  $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
  if(! $conn )
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db('test');
  $radioAnswer = $_POST['radioAnswer'];


   ...
}
?>
```

Comment: "*It doesnt work*" isn't as helpful as you might think. Be specific, include error messages, and expected results and actual results. Turn on error debugging if you don't have it on... use this at the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Also `mysql_*` functions are **depreciated**, and fully **removed** from php 7+.

Comment: Better start using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` if you're new and still learning. Since `mysql` is deprecated already and is not used in the newest version of PHP.

Comment: You can submit it without the form action by using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I think, will want to name the radio buttons the same. So:

```
<form class="cc-selector" id="form-id" method="POST">
    <label><input id="happy" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" value="happy"/></label>
    <label><input id="sad" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" value="sad"/></label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
```

And your php will need to change also:

```
<?php if(array_key_exists('radioAnswer', $_POST)) {


  $dbhost = 'localhost';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = 'rootpassword';
  $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
  if(! $conn )
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db('test');
  $radioAnswer = $_POST['radioAnswer'];


   ...
}
```

If you want to have it happen onclick, you can submit the form using javascript onclick, here is an example how:

```
<input id="happy" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();" />
```

Comment: Would i be able to do a onclick from the radio button and not have to submit the form via button would it be onclick="document.getElementById('radioAnswer').click();"

Comment: That's close, that would be more like jQuery's syntax for click. The correct way for vanilla javascript would be like this:

`onclick="document.getElementById('radioAnswer').onclick = radioBtnClickFunction"`

`<script>

function radioBtnClickFunction() { 
   alert("works");
   ... code ...

};
</script>`

Comment: For this, to submit, give the form an id, "form-id". Then add this attribute to each radio button input: `onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();"`, here is a link to a resource that can help you: [On Click Action](https://www.formget.com/javascript-submit-form/)

Answer (score 1):

You should name the radio buttons the same.

```
<div class="cc-selector">
        <label><input id="happy" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" value="happy"/></label>
        <label><input id="sad" type="radio" name="radioAnswer" value="sad"/></label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
      </div>
```

now to get the response you can use

```
$response = $_REQUEST['radioAnswer'];
```

this will show you if the user has selected happy or sad radio. Use mysqli_* or PDO functions to query the database, mysql_* functions are deprecated. You may want to use [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp) for reference.

Comment: Thats one of the many issues covered. You could tackle them all... but you'll be writing a ton of new code ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form name="form" action="sample2.php" class="cc-selector" method="post" >

       <label class="label">
        <input type="image" name="Opinion" value="Positive" src="happy.png" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();"/>

       </label>

       <label class="label">
        <input type="image" name="Opinion" value="Negative" src="sad.png" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();"/>
       </label>
      </form>
```